# How can i make an object perform an action on condition that the past animation has finished

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

In a 2d game I coded an enemy to attack the player, so that when the player gets close to the enemy this one starts to chase him and hits him when it is close enough. When the enemy starts his attack animation and the player moves out of the trigger attack area, the attack animation is interrupted and it continues chasing the player.

```
 void Update()
    {
        if(!attackMode)
        {
            Move();
        } 

void EnemyLogic()
     {
        distance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.position);
        if(distance > attackDistance)
            {
               StopAttack();
            }
     }

void Move()
    {
       anim.SetBool("canWalk",true);
       
        if(!anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("LightBandit_Attack"))
        {
            Vector2 targetPosition = new Vector2(target.position.x, transform.position.y);
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

void StopAttack()
    {
        cooling = false;
        attackMode = false;
        anim.SetBool("Attack", false);
    }
```

This is the part of the code that makes the transition from the attack animation to the run animation and makes the enemy move. i don t know what i need to change or add to make the enemy not interrupting the attack animation.

Comment: Well, you do `if(distance > attackDistance)  { StopAttack();   }` would probably start here and first check if you are already in attack animation and innrhat case skip the check or configure your animator transitions better so the clip first runs to end and then transitions (=> see Exit Time)

Comment: Ahh yes u r right!! for sure the fastest way, the only problem it s that the character would still start moving during the attack animation but i want it to not move while attacking

Answer (score 0):

I would check if animator is already in attack state. Like this

```
string animation = "attackAnimation";
 bool attackAnimPlaying = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName(animation);

if(distance > attackDistance && !attackAnimPlaying){
//stop
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn t work. thanks for suggesting!! :)